# findone operation to check wheather a value present in json object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

in my table, I have tagId column, which contains data in JSON format. example [1,2]; I need to find the id of that row by checking whether the tag id is present or not. for example, if tag id 2 is present in [1,2] so I need to fetch that corresponding table row

Node.js sequlze SQL code is used

i try in,contains and many solution in google but i just retriveing empty data

```
const response = await db.UserTag.findAll({
  where: { tagId: { [Op.contains]: ["1"] } },
});
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const const response = await db.UserTag.findAll({
  where: {
    tagId: {
      [Op.regexp]: 1,
    },
  },
  attributes: ['Id'],
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.